# Layout problem: gap before question too small

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, layout

So I noticed this today:

[image: Narwhals, Narwhals, swimming in the ocean!]

This spacing seems inconsistent with other SE sites:

[image: Causin' a commotion, because they are so awesome!]

It seems to be the same on Meta too. Has it always been like this, and I've only just noticed, or has it changed recently?

Comment: This is happening on most Stack Exchange sites it seems: [reported it on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/padding-at-the-top-of-question-bodies-has-gone-missing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed (I see it live already). From [balpha on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/padding-at-the-top-of-question-bodies-has-gone-missing/110948#110948):

> Same reason as [The "start a bounty" popup box could not be loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110926/the-start-a-bounty-popup-box-could-not-be-loaded/110928#110928) – another `#question` that wasn't changed to `.question`. Fixed now, thanks.